# Splitting string based on intervals

Tags: r, regex

I have strings that contain intervals (open/closed/mixed) intervals that are then split by commas. I would then like to split these strings by the commas *outside the intervals*.

e.g.

```
"(-Inf, 2], (2, 8), [8, 9], (9, 10), [10, Inf)"
```

would become

```
[1] "(-Inf, 2]"
[2] "(2, 8)"
[3] "[8, 9]"
[4] "(9, 10)"
[5] "[10, Inf)"
```

I've tried various approaches but can't seem to get it to work for all the interval types.

Comment: @27ϕ9 Thank you. I'm a little surprised I missed that. Post as answer so that I can accept, if you want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a positive lookbehind to split on the commas outside the intervals:

```
strsplit("(-Inf, 2], (2, 8), [8, 9], (9, 10), [10, Inf)", "(?<=[\\]\\)]),", perl = TRUE) 
# [[1]]
# [1] "(-Inf, 2]"  " (2, 8)"    " [8, 9]"    " (9, 10)"   " [10, Inf)"
```